# How manages the memory to use copied array and dictionary?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, memory, dictionary

I have removable data in Array (`NSMutableArray`)...(When data remove in array, array uses other place. so, I retain that.)

also, I used copy command....but I not found how release that.

```
NSMutableArray *arrRemovable;

NSMutableDictionary *dicData; (alloc, and init)

[_dicData setObject:[arrRemovable copy] forKey:@"DATA1"];
```

### (it's already retain count 2)

I want not to make the arrRemovable variable..
i want to subtract retain count.

[[_dicData objectForKey:@"DATA1"] release]
I using that, but analysis tool warned me.

Message is "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"

help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
NSMutableArray *copyOfArrRemovable = [arrRemovable copy]; 
[_dicData setObject:copyOfArrRemovable forKey:@"Data1"];
[copyOfArrRemovable release];
```

This is assuming I understood the question correctly. If not, please explain.

Hope that helps.

Comment: your answer is normal..I know that,too. I want to not use the copyOfArrRemovable variable. there are 35 Arrays. I don't want to make 35 NSMutable variables. What can I do?